# Can on-premise Active Directory(AD) operate as a user store for an Azure website using membership services?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, active-directory, azure-web-app-service

I have a MVC3 ASP.NET 4.5 web application on Azure Websites.

Can on-premise Active Directory(AD) operate as a user store for an Azure website (WAWS) using membership services?

What happens to the roles, which I currently use as attributes on actions.

Any enlightenment appreciated?

EDIT

Just found that one can configure Membership services to use AD as the membership store, ie:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="ADConnectionString" connectionString="LDAP://testdomain.test.com/CN=Users,DC=testdomain,DC=test,DC=com" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Whether this would work into an on-premise AD store I am unsure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your AD instance would have to be accessible from the internet, which seems like a bit of a security risk.

Normally what you are trying to do is accomplished via federation.  A couple of options:

1. Deploy AD FS on-premises to serve as an internet-accessible
   authentication proxy for your AD  instance.

   - Pro: Somewhat easier to set up
   - Con: Your app must connect from the Azure datacenter to your on-premises data center for every directory read
2. Synch your on-premises directory with your Azure AD and point your app at that.

   - Pro: Directory is in closer proximity to your app
   - Con: Somewhat more complicated to set up

**Disclaimer:** This is from the application/developer perspective.  I'm sure there are other factors to consider from the directory perspective.

Comment: Thanks for this. Yes, thought there may be security issues, so thanks for your suggestions. I did pick up on the sync AD feature to Azure AD, however I have the slight concern that my client has not moved to Azure yet, and may baulk at the idea of syncing their AD to Azure for the sake of one web app. However it may be straight forward, and nothing to be worried about?

Comment: Which is the best of these 2 approaches?

Comment: It depends :) Updated answer.